# Ubuntu 16.04 changing IP address - Restarting networking service, switches o old IP address

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, ip

I am trying to change the IP address of an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have tried the following

```
ifconfig eth0 {ip} netmask {mask-ip}
```

Post that I try restarting the networking service which changes the IP address back to old one. I have also tried changing the IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` file but it doesn't work as well.

Could you please help in effectively changing the IP address of a Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the below answer is somewhat correct @bobmorgandy but the actual problem I found was that the MAC address assigned by Hyper-V was different than the MAC address defined by the cloud provider, which in turn didn't updated the IPv6 address. After providing the correct MAC address, I was able to update it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of Ubuntu:
go to /etc/network/interfaces and change the address line as follows, , where 10.0.0.41 is used as the example target IP address - ensure static is specified:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.41
```

In the newer versions of Ubuntu, go to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml (or other yaml file in this location) and modify the addresses line as follows, where 10.0.0.41 is used as the example target IP address:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            addresses: [10.0.0.41/24]
```

Reboot when complete, of course, and use ifconfig to check that your IP has changed.